# Multiple PostgreSQL running as primary server on pgpool

Tags: postgresql, linux, pgpool

I'm facing a problem with my pgpool setup. Currently, this is my requirement based on the pgpool documentation [here](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/simple_sr_setting2/index.html) :

Server A  : Install with PostgreSQL database. Run as primary server

Server B  : Install with PostgreSQL database. Run as secondary server

Server C  : Install with pgpool and pgpoolAdmin. Run as web server.

The problem starts when I'm accessing the pgpoolAdmin through Apache web server.

[image: pgpool Status]

Both of the PostgreSQL databases are running as primary servers. It is supposed to run one as standby and the other as primary, for when failover occurs. Maybe I've messed up something when configuring this set up, but I don't know what it is. Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT** : Below is my pgpool.conf file

```
master_slave_mode = on                                      
master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'   
wd_life_point = 3    
wd_lifecheck_query = 'SELECT 1'   
backend_socket_dir = '/tmp'    
backend_hostname0 = '192.168.1.134'   
backend_port0 = 5432   
backend_weight0 = 1    
backend_data_directory0 = '/usr/local/pgsql/data'   
backend_flag0= 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'    
backend_hostname1 = '192.168.1.136'    
backend_port1 = 5432   
backend_weight1 = 1   
backend_data_directory1 = '/usr/local/pgsql/data'   
backend_flag1= 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
```

Comment: Now what have you specified in the config?  Sounds like you feel a discrepancy between it and the status report above.

Comment: @dezso what do you want to see?is it the posgresql conf or the pgpool conf?i can put it in my post

Comment: We need the pgpool conf, I think.

Comment: i've already edit.see my post above

Comment: @dezso i've see you have edited my post.so can you tell me what is the problem with my setup?

Comment: Sorry, I've a bit lost on this.  Does the problem still persist?  Anyway, edited your post to bring it up to the public.

Comment: nope..the problem still occur.and we almost given up for this.
hopefully there are another solution for this.Or else we trying other middleware such as pg bouncer or slony

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but as I have just been through the pain of configuring pgpool, and have encountered similar problems, I'll answer here.

I have exactly the same setup, but I made the choice to go through this excellent [tutorial](https://fatdragon.me/blog/2016/05/postgresql-ha-pgpool-ii-part-1) (in 6 parts ouch). It intends to build a full pgpool/pgsql HA infrastructure, where there is no single point failure with one pgpool server, as two pgpool are installed along two postgresql primary and standby servers in streaming replication.

Anyway it is quite easy to adapt in order to keep pgpool one one separate server like I did.

Regarding our problem here, I think it could be related to an incomplete primary/standby setup. And anyone having this problem shall try to setup streaming replication at postgresql level before trying to attach new node with pgpool (particularly when you have a database that is not empty).

In `postgresql.conf` I would check `REPLICATION` section on both servers and make sure that the standby server has `hot_standby = on`. Make sure also that you have correct `recovery.conf` file on standby server.

Comment: The link you provided is forbidden. ( [tutorial](https://www.itenlight.com/blog/2016/05/18/PostgreSQL+HA+with+pgpool-II+-+Part+1) )

Comment: Both links are dead. Here is a wayback machine link
https://web.archive.org/web/20210226215520/fatdragon.me/blog/2016/05/postgresql-ha-pgpool-ii-part-1